# gnuplot linux to windows

Tags: linux, windows, gnuplot

I am running the below Gnuplot code in Linux.

I want to know how I can run the same code on windows?
Thanks a lot!

```
reset

set termoption dash


set terminal postscript portrait enhanced color "Helvetica" 10

set output '| ps2pdf - Plot.pdf'

set datafile separator "," 
mag = 5

set grid

set border 31 lw 1

set key off

set style line 1 lt 1 lw 10 pt 6 ps 0.4 lc rgb '#D3D3D3'

TET_0011 = "/home/soheil/university/quadratic/KAPPA & MU/TET-VOIGT-SR-0.01.txt"

plot TET_0011 u 1:4 w l ls 1 title "VOIGT"
```

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 0):

Gnuplot is supported on windows using [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

Checkout the binary [download page](http://www.gnuplot.info/download.html) for gnuplot windows binaries.

The gnuplot code you post above will remain the same.

Comment: he's piping postscript output to ps2pdf - not sure they are available

Answer (score 0):

The only problem i see on windows is the lack os `ps2pdf`

Fortunately, you could set to generate PDF directly, instead of `set terminal postscript ...` you should have `pdfcairo` terminal

```
set terminal pdfcairo OPTIONS
```

It is available on gnuplot on windows, v5.0.x